# Microsoft Graph API bulk presence lookup

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using the following code to retrieve multiple user presences:

```
var presences = await _graphServiceClient.Communications
    .GetPresenceByUserIds(ids)
    .Request
    .PostAsync();
```

Is there a similar request to get the ids in bulk? I am having to look them up one by one and this is causing a bit of a delay in the whole request - especially if I need ~20 presences

Edited to add:
The code the get users' ids is:

```
currentUser = await _graphServiceClient.Users[email]
    .Request()
    .Select(u => new
        {
           u.Id
        })
    .GetAsync();
return currentUser.Id;
```

So I query each email and append the result id to a list / array. Adding u.Presence in the select filter returns a null Presence.

Comment: Could you add code how do you get ids? How do you search for the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter users by `userPrincipalName` and using `in` operator. The limitation is that you can query only 15 users this way.

```
var queryOptions = new List<Option>
{
    new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel","eventual"),
    new QueryOption("$count", "true")
};
var userIds = await client.Users
      .Request(queryOptions)
      .Select("id")
      .Filter("userPrincipalName in ('user1@xxx.com',...,'user15@xxx.com')")
      .GetAsync();
```

It will reduce the number of calls but it isn't still one call.

But the query above can be used in a batch request

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch

{
    "requests": [
        {
            "url": "/users?$filter=userPrincipalName in ('user1@xxx.com',...,'user15@xxx.com')&$select=id&$count=true",
            "method": "GET",
            "id": 1,
            "headers": {
                "ConsistencyLevel": "eventual"
            }
        },
        {
            "url": "/users?$filter=userPrincipalName in ('user16@xxx.com',...,'user30@xxx.com')&$select=id&$count=true",
            "method": "GET",
            "id": 2,
            "headers": {
                "ConsistencyLevel": "eventual"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

C# code:

```
var queryOptions = new List<Option>
{
    new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel","eventual"),
    new QueryOption("$count", "true")
};

var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();

var requestMessage1 = client.Users
    .Request(queryOptions)
    .Select("id")
    .Filter("userPrincipalName in ('user1@xxx.com',...,'user15@xxx.com')")
    .GetHttpRequestMessage();

batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(requestMessage1);

var requestMessage2 = client.Users
    .Request(queryOptions)
    .Select("id")
    .Filter("userPrincipalName in ('user16@xxx.com',...,'user30@xxx.com')")
    .GetHttpRequestMessage();

batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(requestMessage2);

var batchResponseContent = await client.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
```

In the batch, you can define up to 20 requests, so you can get id of ~300 users.